# Conditional Statements in Spring @preauthorize EL

Tags: spring, spring-security

Hi here my problem is to add conditional statements in @preauthorize spring annotation
,I need to give Users_view and Users_manage permission for principal but i cant add both permission like below 
`@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'com.foo', 'USERS_VIEW','USERS_MANAGE')")`
 in @preauthorize ,I have an idea like below

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#id, 'com.foo', 'USERS_VIEW') OR hasPermission(#id, 'com.foo', 'USERS_VIEW')")
```

Will spring support conditional clauses in @preauthorize so if not what is the solution for this.(**Here I need to use only @preauthorize rather than hasroles[]**)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it will. But I have not tried in uppercase, in lowercase it is sure (I mean `or` instead of `OR`). See [Logical operators](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operators-logical) section of the official documentation.